# Angular 2 (Mock Ionic2) -- No provider for App

Tags: unit-testing, angular, mocking, ionic2, angular2-testing

I'm trying to create a `spec.ts` for my application. Sadly this is using the [LoadingController](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/loading/LoadingController/) from `ionic-angular`. Now when I'm trying to configure the module, I will need to provide it with the LoadingController (since it's in the constructor of the module).

The problem I'm currently running into is that the LoadingController wants to be provided with a `App` object/instance. (`_app: App` params)

I was desperate so I asked Ionic themselves. [github #8539](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/8539)

But they closed my question because it was a question and not an issue, although I'm having issues realizing it which they haven't responded to. It would be a shame if this is impossible/no one knows how, since it's a pretty cool feature and it affects not just the LoadingController, f.e. the AlertController and ToastController are affected by this as well.

My testbed configuration atm:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [EventsPage],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    providers: [
      {provide: APICaller, useValue: mockAPICaller},
      {provide: NavController, useValue: mockNavController },
      {provide: LoadingController, useValue: ???????}, //it seems like everything I try to enter here fails.
    ],
    imports: [FormsModule]
  });
```

And the EventsPage constructor:

```
constructor(public apiCaller: APICaller, public navCtrl: NavController,
             public loadingCtrl: LoadingController){}
```

**EDIT: usage of LoadingController**

```
getEvents() {
    // setup a loadingscreen
     let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Loading..."
    }); 
   // present the loadingscreen
    loading.present();

    // reset the noEvents boolean.
    this.noEvents = true;

    // call the api and get all events
    this.apiCaller.getEvents()
    .subscribe(response => {
      // response is list of events
      this.events = response;
      // if the event is not empty, set noEvents to false.
      if (this.events.length > 0) {
        this.noEvents = false;
      }
      // close the loading message.
     loading.dismiss();
    });
  }
```

Which will then result in this loadingspinner (with different text)

[image: ionic's Loading]

Comment: What does the class you are using the `LoadingController` in look like? Basically show how you are using the `LoadingController` in the controller. I don't use Ionic, but I'm pretty sure creating a mock shouldn't be too difficult if I knew how you used it

Comment: @peeskillet edited the answer, `loadingController.create({content:...})` creates an object of `Loading` which can be presented on your screen like in the edited answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With this type of thing, you probably don't want to test anything in the UI (in regards to using the `LoadingController`). What you should be testing is the behavior of the component. So when you create the mock for the `LoadingController` what you want to do is spy on the critical methods, and your expectations should test to make sure that you are calling the methods on the `LoadingController`. Doing this you can write tests like

```
expect(loadingController.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
// or
expect(loadingController.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith(args);
```

Your mocks don't have to follow the actual structure of the item being mocked either. For instance `LoadingController.create` returns a `Loading` object. In your mock, you don't need to have this. If you want you can just return the mock itself, when calling `create`, and in the mock just have the methods that `Loading` would have.

Remember that you are just testing the behavior of the controller. It doesn't matter what the mock `LoadingController` actually does, just that you are able to called the methods, and check in the test to make sure they are called *when* they are expected to be called. Other than that, you should just *assume* the real `LoadingController` works.

So you could have something like

```
let mockLoadingController = {
  // Tried `create: jasmine.createSpy('create').and.returnValue(this)
  // seem this doesn't work. We just create the spy later
  create: (args: any) => { return this; },
  present: jasmine.createSpy('present'),
  dismiss: jasmine.createSpy('dismiss')
};
spyOn(mockLoadingController, 'create').and.returnValue(mockLoadingController);

{ provide: LoadingController, useValue: mockLoadingController }
```

Then in you tests you can just do something like

```
it('should create loader with args ...', () => {
  ...
  expect(mockLoadingController.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith({...})
})
it('should present the loader', () => {
  ...
  expect(mockLoadingController.present).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
it('should dismiss the loader when the api call returns', async(() => {
  ..
  expect(mockLoadingController.dismiss).toHaveBeenCalled();
}))
```

Here's what I used right now to test

```
class LoadingController {
  create(args: any) { return this; }
  present() {}
  dismiss() {}
}

@Component({
  template: ''
})
class TestComponent {
  constructor(private loadingController: LoadingController) {}

  setEvents() {
    let loading = this.loadingController.create({hello: 'world'});

    loading.present();
    loading.dismiss();
  }
}

describe('component: TestComponent', () => {
  let mockLoadingController;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockLoadingController = {
      create: (args: any) => { return this; },
      present: jasmine.createSpy('present'),
      dismiss: jasmine.createSpy('dismiss')
    };
    spyOn(mockLoadingController, 'create').and.returnValue(mockLoadingController);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: LoadingController, useValue: mockLoadingController }
      ]
    });
  }));

  it('should calling loading controller', () => {
    let comp = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent).componentInstance;
    comp.setEvents();

    expect(mockLoadingController.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ hello: 'world'});
    expect(mockLoadingController.present).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockLoadingController.dismiss).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**See Also:**

- [Jasmine docs on Spies](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies)

Comment: wow this actually works, thank you so much! spent a good amount of hours trying to figure out what's wrong haha